# Mongo Call does not remove parameters

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

Im using node with mongo, and I want for the mongo get call to stop returning some values, such as _id and uid. Everything that ive read says that this call should work, but when I print the json value on my UI, it still has those values.

```
app.get('/users', async function(req, res){
    console.log("Getting User Info!");

    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db('database');
    var uidparam = req.header("uid");
    
    db.collection("users").findOne({"uid": uidparam}, { _id: 0, uid: 0, }, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(result);
      });
});
```

Ive also tried

```
{ "_id": false, "uid": false, }
```

and

```
{ _id: false, uid: false, }
```

and

```
{ '_id': 0, 'uid': 0, }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following along with [this example](https://docs.mongodb.com/drivers/node/usage-examples/findOne#example) for Node, it looks like you need to specify a `projection` field for the options document. It would look like this:

```
{
  projection: {
    _id: 0,
    uid: 0
  }
}
```

Comment: yep, this was it! Not sure why though, I dont see it in other parts of the documentation

Comment: You can find links to documentation for the MongoDB Node drivers [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/). The API links in particular are useful for finding what arguments you can pass to functions. @EugeneRozental